# What is the use of flex <s:div> tag

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I observed that flex has `<s:div>` tag But I don't know the use of it.  I think it may use like html formatting. It will be helpful to format a texts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It used in [TextFlow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html) objects. TextFlow object is a part of [TLF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ffe.html) (Text Layout Framework). I recommend you to read some articles about this because it is a really powerful tool. And about mxml tags associated with TextFlow - there are few example of usage: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ffa.html

And [supported tags](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ff6.html).